# List broken by a float

Tags: floats, lists, page-breaking

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5][1-10]

Consider the following cases:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item case 1
\item case 2
\item case 3
\item case 4
\item case 5
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

It is not good that the list is broken by a float:

[image]

How to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\begin{figure}[hbp]
```

here so the top float is not allowed.

If you do not want bottom floats either then also omit `b`. Note that `h` is only used if the float can be positioned where it appears in the source, so the float can not appear mid-page after the list unless you move it in the source file to that location.

Comment: Now the float is awkwardly in the very bottom

Comment: @Viesturs were where _do_ you want it?:-)  Your example in the question included `b` option, if you do not want bottom floats you do not need to allow them, use `[hp]`

Comment: Immediately after the list?

Comment: @Viesturs latex never makes a mid page float other than `here` so that is not an option unless you move the figure in the source

Comment: If you could incorporate your last comment into your answer, then I could accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Load package `enumitem` and then

```
\begin{itemize}[before=\minipage{\dimexpr\linewidth-\labelwidth},after=\endminipage]
```

Comment: Now the float is awkwardly between the introductory statement and the list.

Comment: What did you expect?